# Silex Routing issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-routing, silex

A simple doubt regarding Silex Routing. I am  very new to Silex, and basically I am learning it, as far as everything is going so well, and here is the issue(??) -

This is my index.php ->

```
    require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new Silex\Application();

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\UrlGeneratorServiceProvider());
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

$app->get('/', function() {
    return 'Hello World!';
});

$app->get('/hello', function() {
    return 'Hello From HELLO!';
});

$app->error(function (\Exception $e, $code) use($app) {
    switch ($code) {
        case 404:
            $message = "Oooops Not Found";
            break;
        default:
            $message = $app['twig']->render('error500.html.twig');
    }
    return new Response($message, $code);
});

$app->run();
```

issue is regarding routing, It is working as long as we try to access home, or /hello(http://mysite.dev or http://mysite.dev/hello ). but if I try to access
a link, that doesn't exist, like this - http://mysite.dev/hello/blah it will return a 404 page($app->error()) as expected, but if I delete /blah part and try to enter again in browser (http://mysite.dev/hello) - still I get 404, to access the site i have to go all the way back to root(ie http://mysite.dev). I dont know if I am missing some config or something else or may  be a foolish one, but please I am a starter in Coding.

HERE IS A GREAT EXAMPLE: - go to https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md it will lead you to composer documentation getting started page, and if you add some thing at the end of this url like this https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md/blah - it will give you 'Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.' error, ok and if you want to go back to getting started page, if you try to delete /blah and enter again, no way you still get same error page, can anybody explain about this.

same in here http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route is not expecting the trailing forward slash.  Thsi is expected behaviour, and has been discussed at length: https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/issues/149

It is suggested that you define a redundant path, with the slash implicit:

```
$app->get('/hello', function() {
    return 'Hello From HELLO!';
});

$app->get('/hello/', function() {
    return 'Hello From HELLO!';
});
```

Since the second parameter is a callback, this could be:

```
$hello_handler = function() {
    return 'Hello From HELLO!';
};
//or
$hello_handler = array($object, 'handler_method');

$app->get('/hello',  $hello_handler);
$app->get('/hello/', $hello_handler);
```

Or whatever easy to use method you come up with.

The reason for this is that `/index.html` is not the same as `/index.html/`.

Comment: Not a problem my friend.